# Unable to get IAM security credentials for AWS S3

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This error is driving me crazy, had the same issue with a lambda web api, but that worked when uploaded, so that will do for now

This project however will be a NuGet package, and i need to be able to simply upload a file to S3

I have the code in place using the following : "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html"

im trying to run this local, but getting the Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service." error

within visual studio, i can see the AWS Explorer, and i can create a bucket from here... so i have my user setup... but when i run local... there is no user???

i know its going to be a one line missing value somewhere :(

Comment: How did you setup the user for AWS explorer? Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: That error message is related to the last of a long list of credentials providers that the SDK tries to use to find credentials. It means that the SDK could not find credentials anywhere in its supported list. If you are running locally on Mac/Linux then credentials would typically be in `~/.aws/credentials`.

Comment: in AWS Explorer I added a new profile, this adds the user to the credentials file.. i can see the profile does exist in this file : (

Comment: found the issue, needed to create a "default" profile... cant see in the documentation anywhere saying this :(  will write up an answer soon with more details

Answer (score 3):

Thank you @Geeshan for your answer, it gave me some direction on where to look

However, I had my credentials file setup, but the answer to my question was you also need to have a profile setup with the name "default"

Also, now know that you dont need a matching "default" IAM user.

On the AWS IAM User page, you create your users as normal, no need to create a default user.  In Visual studio, when you create a new profile, if your profile is named "default", and you enter they key and secret key for one of your IAM user, running your application will use that user (I miss understood this profile name, and was assuming it needs to match your IAM user, so initially i create a "Default" IAM user. which i now know, is not needed)

If you dont want to use the default then, you can choose a user by using "TryGetProfile and TryGetAWSCredentials in your application code (see below)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is due to missing credentials in your local machine. Setting up the AWS Explorer will not provide the credentials to running your code.

One way to setup the credentials is to use a Credentials File in `C:\users\awsuser\.aws\credentials` (asuming you are using windows).
The following is an example of a profile in the credentials file.

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = {accessKey}
aws_secret_access_key = {secretKey}
```

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html) you can read more about managing credentials for .Net

Comment: Thank you, however that didnt work : (, my credentials do exist in this location, with the key and access key set, I just created a new IAM user, then added a new profile to Visual studio AWS Explorer, in doing that, i can see this new user in the credentials fie... i hit run, and still get the same error :(  how does my code know to use the new profile? am i missing some other config values somewhere? or is that just based on which profile is active? (I had a read through your link too, helps, makes sense , but still cant get this working

Comment: i tried these "TryGetAWSCredentials TryGetProfile" for my profile name, and they return the details of my profile, I have no idea why this isnt working : (

Comment: found the problem... i needed to create a "default" profile, and it works, or if using a different profile, i need in code to use "TryGetAWSCredentials" and set the awsCredentials to the profile i need.
I will create an answer with more details shortly, ideally want to use the profile a visual studio user is using, otherwise all developers will be using the default profile, and no need to create IAM profiles

Comment: I misunderstood the profile name in VS AWS Explorer... I thought this had to match one of your IAM Users along with the keys.  I didnt need to create a "default" IAM user account, i just had to use the keys from my IAM user, and set Visual Studio profile name to "default".... all makes sense now! thank you for pointing me in the right direction!